# Python xlrd transforms integers and strings into floats

Tags: python, excel, csv, xlrd

I tried succesfully to convers an excel file into csv but it converted all my numbers (despite the fact that they were integers or text in the excel file) to floats.

I know that python reads by default numbers as floats.

is there any chance to turn all my numbers to strings?

my code is bellow

```
def Excel2CSV(ExcelFile, SheetName, CSVFile):
 import xlrd
 import csv
 workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(ExcelFile)
 worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name(SheetName)
 csvfile = open(CSVFile, 'wb')
 wr = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=';', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)

 for rownum in xrange(worksheet.nrows):
     wr.writerow(
         list(x.encode('utf-8') if type(x) == type(u'') else x
              for x in worksheet.row_values(rownum)))

 csvfile.close()
```

thank you for your time

Comment: It shoud not convert _text_ into floats but there is no chance with ”integers” because Excel doesn't make this distinction, so every number is a float. The type test is better expressed as `isinstance(x, unicode)` by the way.

Comment: It's not Python that "reads numbers as floats". It's Excel which stores *every* numeric value as a float. I would use different wording than BlackJack: It's not so much that Excel "doesn't distinguish" between integers and floats; it's that Excel **does not have** any numeric type other than float.

Comment: Depending on what you expect the input to be, you can try parsing the value as an int `unicode(int(worksheet.cell_value(r,c)))`.  This approach will fail if you have a text string "042.0" and you don't want to drop the leading or trailing zeros.  It can fail for boolean and some dates, I think.  More robust is to use the [cell type](http://www.lexicon.net/sjmachin/xlrd.html#xlrd.Cell-class) to figure out how you should transform the cell value.

Answer (score 1):

My work-around has been to treat the Excel file Cell-by-Cell first through a new nested list, and then writing that nested list to a CSV file.

By accessing individual Cell Values, I can convert them to String Data Types which leaves the internals of the cell as-is in the CSV file ( with the String quotation marks removed of course ).

Here's how I access individual Cell Values :

```
for rownum in xrange(worksheet.nrows):
    for col_num in xrange ( worksheet.ncols ) :
        value = str ( worksheet.row (rownum ) [ column_num ].value )
```

I append these treated cell values to a single row and append that single row to a nested list that serves as a copy of the original input excel file.